# comparison the content of a text and csv files

Tags: sed, awk, diff

I need a sample bash script to compare a first line of a file(Result.txt) to first row and column of another file(table.csv), then send the result to an html file.

I am very basic in coding, this is what I found so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
Result.txt="$(head -n 1 < $1|tail -n 1)"
table.csv="$(head -n 1 < $2|tail -n 1)"
test "$R.txt" = "$sheet.csv" && (echo The same; exit 0)
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: even if your shell allows you to have '.'s chars in a variable name, it's not a good idea. `Result="..."` is much easier. AND you really meant the last line of your code uses a `Result.txt` variable, and not just `R.txt`. right? `"$R.txt"` will always be empty. You'll also need to provide some kind of specifcation for what your html file is supposed to look like. Read up about awk, and it's `printf` statement. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly tweaking your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
Res=$(head -n 1 "$1")
tab=$(head -n 1 "$2")
[[ $Res == $tab ]] && echo The same
```

Notes

- "dot" is not a valid identifier (i.e. variable name) character: valid is letters, numbers and underscore, and the first character cannot be a number.
- if you're doing `head -1`, there's no need to pipe that into `tail -1`
- I think `[[` is more readable than `test`, primarily because `[[` forces you to have `]]`
- parentheses launch a subshell which is overkill for an echo statement.

  - the exit will only exit the subshell not your program
  - if you have multiple statements, use `if ...; then ...; fi` -- it's more readable.